# How to change a pandas column with lists in every row to strings

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, numpy, nlp

I have used a Named Entity Recognizer to extract skills from job vacancies. This worked, but now the entities are in a pandas column as lists. I want to create a new column with just the skills and using the replace function or astype(str) both do not work.

Here you can see my dataframe:

```
                                                Skills
0                  [(Responsibility), (communication)]
1    [(responsibility), (responsibility), (Leadersh...
2                                      [(Flexibility)]
3                                                   []
4                                      [(communicate)]
Name: skills, dtype: object
```

This is how I eventually want my column to look like:

```
                                          Skills_clean
0                        Responsibility, communication
1           responsibility, responsibility, Leadership
2                                          Flexibility
3                                                  NaN
4                                          communicate
Name: skills, dtype: object
```

So I want to lose all the square and round brackets, or does any body have a better idea on how to do this?

Comment: Can you provide some expected results?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just added the expected results. I want the list in every column to be a string

Answer (score 0):

this, replace worked for me

```
ds = pd.Series(['(Responsibility), (communication)]','[(responsibility), (responsibility), (Leadership)',
'[(Flexibility)]','[(communicate)]'])

ds.str.replace(r'\(|\)|\[|\]',' ', regex=True)
```

```
0                    Responsibility ,  communication  
1      responsibility ,  responsibility ,  Leadership 
2                                        Flexibility  
3                                        communicat
```